# Stop key propagation in SDL (SDL2) (prevent alt-tab)

Tags: windows, sdl, sdl-2

I'm building a remote desktop application and would like to capture keys like alt-tab and prevent them from forwarding to the client operating system.

I know how to do this in iohook. There is a thread that [discusses the feature](https://github.com/wilix-team/iohook/issues/34), and an [implementation of it](https://github.com/theicfire/iohook/commit/f2e1e14c079e175cc97f314dfcf2203cc1467508). For windows (which I mainly care about at the moment), this works by calling `SetWindowsHookEx` with a first parameter of `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`, and then *not* calling `CallNextHookEx` if key propagation is disabled.

For SDL 1.2, it seems the answer is to use `SDL_WM_GrabInput`. However, this looks to be retired in SDL 2. There is a Stack Overflow post about how to grab the [mouse in SDL 2](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33519/trap-mouse-in-sdl), but not the keyboard.

What's the best way to disable keyboard propagation given that I'm using SDL2?

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution? I'm also interested in this problem

[if you see this and didn't find a sln then pls respond no haha, just so ik]

Comment: I haven't figured this out, but I ended up building something that didn't need this problem solved